# Add item programmatically - Android

Tags: java, android

I created this item in xml:

```
<com.example.alexandre_pc.beerin.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconViewUser"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@mipmap/user"
/>
```

I need to create this item programmatically and add to a `LinearLayout`.
In my Activity I created a `LinearLayout`.

```
 LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
 linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40, 90);
 layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,5,0);
 linear.addView(item, layoutParams);
```

But I dont have idea how to create it programmatically. How can I do it?

Comment: My guess is that you should create a view class. Refer to this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import com.example.alexandre_pc.beerin.RoundedImageView;
```

in onCreate()

```
//create your View

    RoundedImageView yourName = new RoundedImageView();

//set LayoutParameters

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) yourName.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = yourHeight;
            layoutParams.width = yourWidth;
    yourName.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

//set scaleType

     yourName.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.ANY_SCALE_TYPE);
//setResource
     yourName.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourDrawable);
```

then, do as you did originally to add newly created View